# How to send raw cookie string in Rails functional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, request, env

I'm looking to send raw cookie string to application controller for testing. One of the 'before filters' must scan raw cookie data (unescaped '+' => ' ') and decrypt it.

```
request.env['rack.request.cookie_string']
```

I tried several approaches with @cookies, @request.cookies etc., none of them worked. When the test executed 'get page', cookie wasn't found.

Answer (score 2):

A solution to this problem is to execute:

```
@request.env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = your_unescaped_cookie_string
```

before

```
get page
```

in the functional test